# Configure Jenkins CSP for Ubuntu Service

Tags: server, services, jenkins

I upgraded to v2.2 of Jenkins on my server and I want to relax the new Content Security Policy configuration. I can successfully run

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "")
```

which temporarily sets the value and make the HTML output display properly. However when I restart Jenkins the value needs to be changed again. The web page says to run

```
java -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP= -jar jenkins.war
```

however the only file is located at `/usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war` and when I run the command on that file it tries to setup a new Jenkins instance.

Is there a different file or way to run this command for an Ubuntu service?

Comment: Creating a new instance is the behaviour I would expect. Usually the server on which Jenkins is running is never switched off so you only need to enter the command once. Are you looking to run multiple instances of Jenkins and only set this property once or do you want a way to start Jenkins with a relaxed CSP every time you turn on the server?

Comment: Everytime I turn on the server. There have been a few versions released of jenkins recently. Everytime I upgrade it restarts the jenkins service and I have to enter the command again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up modifying `/etc/default/jenkins`. There should be a line that sets a `JAVA_ARGS` variable. I copied `-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=` a described on the jenkins website into that variable.

Answer (score 1):

To run Jenkins every time you restart the server with the option to relax the content security policy, run it as a service with the options you require.

1. Download `jenkins.war` file to any convenient destination, eg. `/home/jenkins_user`
2. Create service file `/etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service` specifying the relaxed security policy
3. Reload service manager: `systemctl daemon-reload`
4. That's it! Now manage the service

Full instructions including examples are given here [Installing Jenkins as a Linux Daemon](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Unix+daemon)

Comment: Thanks for your help. It ended up getting me to the right place.